# Firebase snapshot react promise how to get the variable outside?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to get the variable `hours / minutes / secondes` outside my firebase snapshot so i can return an error message in my promise ! How can i achieve that ? My variable `hours` is undefined when i go outside the firebase function?   ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
 addQuestion(formData) {
    //  console.log('addquestion')
      const {
        theQuestion,
      } = formData;

      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        // Are they a user?
        const UID = await Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        if (!UID) return reject({ message: errorMessages.memberNotAuthd });


        await FirebaseRef.child('questions').orderByChild('author').equalTo(UID).limitToLast(1)
        .once("value").then(snapshot => {

          snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

            var value = childSnapshot.val();
            const LastQuestionTime =  value.timestamp



            var dateFuture = new Date(LastQuestionTime);
            var dateNow = new Date();

            var seconds = Math.floor((dateNow - (dateFuture))/1000);
            var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
            var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
            var days = Math.floor(hours/24);

            hours = hours-(days*24);
            minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
            seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);

        })

        if (hours <= 0) return reject({ message: 'error '+60-minutes+' minutes'});
      });



        // Validation rules
        if (!theQuestion) return reject({ message: 'Veuillez écrire une question' });


        var userInfo = {
          question : theQuestion,
          author : UID,
          timestamp: Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,

         }; //use
        // Go to Firebase
        return Firebase.database().ref('questions').push(userInfo)
          .then(async () => {


          //  this.replaceRecipes(data);
            return resolve();
          }).catch(reject);
      }).catch((err) => { throw err.message; });
    },


  }),
};
```

Comment: any luck with your problem, Slown1970?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of information in your question post about the context where you are trying to use the variables defined in the `await`-ed "snapshot" named parameter variable arrow function, but that might not be necessary to help you, so I will try.

Also, disclaimer: I am going to answer without much knowledge in reactjs, just some contemporary JavaScript.  Also, I am not testing the code snippets below, they are just suggestions and not real code.  Further, I am not analyzing your code's async call structure much, so I could be WAY off, but I think you could *either*:

Attach the variables you need onto an appropriately scoped object variable like:

```
var externalvariable = { prop_one: 'with data' };

function returnsPromise(paramOne) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await awaitFuncCall(paramData).then(snapshotdata => {
            var dateNow = new Date();
            //attach data to external scoped object variable
            externalvariable.date = dateNow;
            //then continue on with async
            //maybe resolve(externalvariable);
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
//use data then here like
usefulFuncWorkCall(externalvariable, externalvariable.date);
//or ((pseudocode(!!)))
let duration = (new Date()) - externalvariable.date;
```

Or, (less likely given what I understand about your code,) you could attach the data you want to use to the variable you are going to return; maybe the "userInfo" variable in your posted code like `userInfo.questionDateData = datedatavariable`;

Final reiteration of disclaiming responsibility: there could be a better actual or more "ReactJS" or codebase convention way to do what you are trying to do, my suggestions deal only with the JavaScript context of the code you have posted.

Hope that helps!